# Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am getting the same error but i used open SSL to create a private key and .csr file.  I am blocked can any one help on this?

Comment: you will need some more information to reproduce the problem. Have a look  here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
 
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.io.IOException: jsse.invalid_ssl_conf
 atorg.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1203)